# Using history.js come to the same scroll position when we click back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, history.js

I want to implement a functionality wherein on clicking the back button, i come back to the same position. A good example may be any ecommerce site.When we scroll down and hit on a product, and click back from the product page, we should reach the same position of the page where that product is.

We use history.js to look up for hashchange and pushstate to save the entries. 
But when I click on back button , it loads to the top of the page rather than the item scroll position. Also, we are laoding the data using AJAX mostly

Im fairly new to jquery, ajax and so do not know how to set the scroll position, save and load during back button click.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `pushState` you can push any information onto the stack you'd like. That could include the scrollTop of the scrollable view and then read it `onpopstate`.

Comment: Ok without doing changes to the history.pushState, can I still get the scrollTop of clicked item and save it

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something like this using `$(document).scrollTop()` and storing that figure in a cookie when leaving the page. My usecase was non-ajaxy but the same idea could easily be adapted with History.js's events replacing page load events, and no need to bother with the cookie for persistence; as @Kyle above mentioned in his comments, History.js lets you store data with pushState that is returned when you return back to that state.

See jQuery's docs: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Comment: OK. Then how would i retrieve a scrollPosition of an product before it redirects to secondPage. So that i can use the same scrollPosition to get to the firstPage? Also while using this will pagination effect the backbutton navigation - when I'm considering a single page but i'll click viewmore to display more data

Comment: I'm doing this <br/> 'code' function scrollTo(toId) { try { var targetOffset = jQuery("#" + toId).offset(); var targetTop = targetOffset.top; jQuery('html, body').delay(100).animate({ scrollTop: targetTop }, 'slow'); } catch(e) { } } – <code>  <br/> In this function, i'm not understanding how to capture the scrollpos and pass it in here. I have a div which has multiple div and each div has a list of items in it. <br/> <br/> How should I get for each list item the position when clicked? Thanks